# Router flash dump unknown filesystem

Tags: hex, dumping

I'm trying to reverse engineering my router firmware after reading an interesting article about an hidden backdoor inside router firmwares from a popular company.

Data has been extracted (using raspberry pi b+ spi) directly from flash because there isn't a downloadable firmware around.

partial serial output

```
Start to decompress!
Booting
Press 'ESC' to enter BOOT console...
Ext. phy is not found. 
Boot from NOR/SPI flash
(c)Copyright Realtek, Inc. 2012
Project RTL8676S LOADER (LZMA)
Version 00.01.02a-rc (Nov 13 2014 17:15:26)
```

binwalk output

```
LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 70744 bytes
(lots of lines like this one)
```

findings

```
0x8000 to 0xE777: bootloader?
0x10000: rootfs start
  first 0x13 byte: unknown data (header ?)
  build date
  string "router.img"
  firmware data
```

I think firmware is encrypted. I can't extract bootloader, kernel and rootfs for static analysis. Is it possible to emulate using qemu?
Fw link: [flashimage](https://www.sendspace.com/file/lc8fya) pass: fi00

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have the same case like you now,
Did you found the true file system and extracted ?
Please give me hint.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, it appears to be a binary image for a MIPS processor (big endian). The image appears to be loaded at offset 0x80000000. There is a subroutine at 0x80001d70 offset which prints out the initial "Start to decompress!" message at PC 0x80001e38. Hopefully that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good starting point indeed. Do you think it's a single file (like VxWorks) as filesytem?

Comment: Following your answer, I found that router os is ThreadX (RTOS) and bootloader is TBS bootloader. Can't find some good info/tools online... But there's some GPL source.